# JSONObject data send to JSONArray

Tags: java, android, json

```
JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject("data");

            Iterator x = data.keys();
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

            while (x.hasNext()){
              String key = (String) x.next();
              jsonArray.put(data.get(key));
            }
            Log.d("TZX", String.valueOf(jsonArray));
```

I have JSONObject on variable data like this

```
{"type":"DISKON","result":"DUPE","data":{"1":{"Code":"DISC2","Description":"DISC SALES","Value":0},"2":{"Code":"DISC1.5%","Description":"DISC1.5%","Value":1.5},"3":{"Code":"DISC 2%","Description":"DISC 2%","Value":2}}}
```

How to i get Object "Value" on JSONObject for send to JSONArray on variable "jsonArray"

Sorry for my grammar and I'm newbie
谢谢

Comment: you want to make JSONARRAY or Get JsonObject from given array?

Comment: the data you have posted is `JSONArray` not `JSONObject`

Comment: sorry i have update my post data json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,

```
JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject("data");
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

Iterator<?> keys = data.keys();

while (keys.hasNext()) {
    String key = (String) keys.next();
    if (data.get(key) instanceof JSONObject) {
        jsonArray.put(((JSONObject) data.get(key)).getString("Value"));
    }
}
Log.e("TZX", String.valueOf(jsonArray));
```

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You are having array, so use `JsonArray` directly to parse data as in

```
JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("data");
List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>();
   for(int i=0;i < array.length();i++){
        values.add(array.getJSONObject(i).getInt("Value"));
   }
```

Comment: org.json.JSONException: Value {"1":{"Code":"DISC2","Description":"DISC SALES","Value":0},"2":{"Code":"DISC1.5%","Description":"DISC1.5%","Value":1.5},"3":{"Code":"DISC 2%","Description":"DISC 2%","Value":2}} at data of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

I have error like this

Comment: my source JSON is JSONObject not a JSONArray

Answer (score 0):

You variable `data` is not JSONObject it's JSONArray.

```
data = [{"Code":"DISC2","Description":"DISC SALES","Value":0},{"Code":"DISC1.5%","Description":"DISC1.5%","Value":1.5},{"Code":"DISC 2%","Description":"DISC 2%","Value":2}]
```

To get JSONObject from array

```
JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(data)
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(obj);

for(int i=0;i<json.length();i++){
    JSONObject e = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String value = e.getString("Value"));
    list.put(value);
}
```

Comment: I want to save "Value" JSONObject to JSONArray
and my source data is JSONObject not a JSONArray

Comment: I guess your given data value was wrong. I Updated the answer. Please check now.

Comment: JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray(obj)

where are "jsonObject" ?

Comment: Sorry. That will be `obj`